# How to fix code for saving multiple images?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on an coding problem with saving multiple images by Python 3. I need to get all my 21 images save finished at once.

I don’t know how to write down the correct code.

```
image_new = ... 
img_dir = 'C:\Users\...' 
for i in image_new:
     j = np.array(i) 
     … 
     j = Image.fromarray(j.astype(np.uint8)) 
     j.save(os.path.join(img_dir, "image1-21.jpg")) #this line has to be fixed
```

I can only save the last image21 into the destination folder with using file.save (os.path.join(image_dir, “image#.jpg”))

Comment: what is `i` in for loop ? i mean is it a number or something else

Comment: thanks, i represents a matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `image_new` contains all 21 images, and that they can be distinguished by their order:

```
image_new = ... 
img_dir = 'C:\Users\...' 
for num, i in enumerate(image_new):
     j = np.array(i) 
     … 
     j = Image.fromarray(j.astype(np.uint8)) 
     j.save(os.path.join(img_dir, "image-{}.jpg".format(num + 1)))
```

Using `enumerate()` to come up with a number from 1-21, and saving the image with that number using `format()`.

Comment: Thanks a million to you economy! you solution helped me out!! Thanks a million again to you!

Comment: Glad to help. Please accept the answer so others know it worked.